# Quale pronome viene usato per augurare qualcosa a una persona?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Sto scrivendo un'email per la mia professoressa. Vorrei sapere se nella seguente frase il pronome "La" in "augurarLa" è giusto:

> Colgo l'occasione per augurarLa il nuovo anno.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie Charo per il benvenuto, anche per la correzione della mia spiegazione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'uso del pronome “Lei” per una persona con cui non sei in rapporti di familiarità è giusto, ma la forma del pronome che hai usato è scorretta, e quella giusta è “Le”.

Il motivo è che “augurare” non si costruisce prendendo come oggetto la persona bensì la cosa che si augura, cioè non si *“augura una persona”, bensì si “augura qualcosa *a* una persona”. Per esempio: “ho augurato buona caccia a mio zio”.

“Lei” si può usare sia come normale pronome personale di 3a persona che come forma di cortesia, ma in ogni caso la sua forma come complemento oggetto (accusativo) è “la” (la mangio, la guardo, la saluto...), mentre quella come complemento di termine (dativo) è “le” (le dico una cosa, le do una cosa...). Quindi diremo:

> Colgo l'occasione per augurarle [o “augurarLe”, a voler essere formali] un buon anno nuovo.

Comment: Tuttavia, in "auguarLe buon anno nuovo", "buon anno nuovo" è il complemento diretto, quindi non so fino a che punto è del tutto corretto dire che non è un verbo transitivo.

Comment: @DaG: Grazie. È proprio quello che volevo sapere. Ho corretto anche il titolo da "Quale pronome viene usato per augurare una persona?" a quello attuale.

Comment: Giusto, @Charo, ora correggo.

Comment: Il motivo è il significato etimologico: tra gli antichi romani, “augurare” era l'attività degli “auguri” (la pronuncia è àuguri), che prevedevano il futuro basandosi su fulmini, volo degli uccelli o altro. Quindi *augurare* è “fare una divinazione” e il complemento oggetto è appunto la divinazione, in questo caso “un buon anno nuovo”.

Answer (score 1):

No, è sbagliato.

La frase corretta è:

> Colgo l’occasione per augurar**Le** buon anno nuovo

Usare il [lei](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-del-lei_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) è una forma di cortesia e rispetto nei confronti dell’insegnante.

Infatti il lei viene usato

> il lei reciproco, nei rapporti formali (ambito di lavoro e
>   istituzionale fra persone che non si conoscono, rapporti gerarchici)

In generale gli [allocutivi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-allocutivi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) sono tipi particolari di pronomi che vengono utilizzati quando ci si rivolge ad altre persone.

Possono essere di due tipi:

1. **Confidenziali**: si usano tra amici, a casa, in contesti informali
2. **di cortesia**: si usano con estranei, superiori gerarchici, in contesti formali

Comment: Ti ringrazio tanto. Mi piacerebbe sapere anche il motivo grammatico. Me lo potresti descrivere gentilmente?

Comment: Il link che ho aggiunto ti spiega in maniera più completa l’utilizzo e l’origine del Lei

Comment: Per quanto riguarda il pronome "Lei" è tutto chiaro. Grazie. Vorrei sapere anche come funziona il pronome diretto / indiretto (...Le, ...La).